# iOS app doesn't show on iTunes Connect when trying to deploy on testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I've read a lot of tutorials and stackoverflow questions similar but I'm unable to figure out what's happening.

So I an an iPad application that I can successfully build in Xcode and on iTunes connect see the app version processing...

[image: App build processing]

After a certain amount of time, it just disappears from the menu. As in it's no longer visible.

I've been following guides similar to: https://www.raywenderlich.com/133121/testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing

But the screenshots on internal testing show's a *Select Version To Test* option which I don't see:

[image: Internal testflight menu]

Does anyone have any idea on how to debug this or what's going on? Because the Archive bundle looks like it's deploying it to the app store, I can see it on the iOS Builds activity but after processing I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: What is in `Activity`? It can't be just disappeared unless you explicitly delete.

Comment: If you think the iTunes Connect web site is misbehaving, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: @Ryan Activity as far as I'm aware should show all my previous builds. In my first screenshot. I'm able to see my current build processing. Then after a few minutes it just disappears without me doing anything.

Comment: You can also delete it. Make sure none of your team member deleted it.

Comment: Have you check your developer email? In the past few weeks I saw that the email with the errors causing the app not to be successfully processed have a significant delay.

Answer (score 0):

Recently we faced this issue couple of times. In iOS Builds section it shows Processing and after some time it disappears.

Reason is due to some errors/ issues with the ipa submitted to iTunesConnect.

Apple sends the error messages to people added in the **Users and Roles** section of iTunesConnect. You can check the people added in the the Users & Roles section and see the mails sent from Apple for any errors related to the app

Comment: Thank you! I think this could be what's happening. I don't seem to be getting any emails though. What's the roles in the iTunes Connect that I need in order to receive emails?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this key in info.plist

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```

Paste it before

```
</dict></plist>
```

This value means that the app uses no encryption, or only exempt encryption. If your app uses encryption and is not exempt, you must set this value to YES/true. Mine is not using encryption so I've set it to false.

It worked for me.

Apple is not going to any send any emails to any user regarding this issue.